# Запись каждого значения в новую строку из массива $_SESSION

Tags: php, массивы

Допустим есть суперглобальный массив $_SESSION['name'] Он содержит следующие данные: ГришаМашаПаша Т.е. всё в кашу. Мне нужно считать эти имена и записать их в новую строку. Т.е. чтобы было 3 строки.

Значит я делаю так: Добавляю к каждому имени символ ';' получается у нас

```
Гриша;Маша;Паша;
```

Далее разделяю нужные мне имена функцией

```
explode(';',$_SESSION['name'])
```

и запускаю цикл

```
foreach ($_SESSION['name'] as $value) {
  $peremennaya = '<tr>'.$value.'</tr>';
}
```

И вот тут ПРОБЛЕМА он выводит мне только последнее значение т.е. Паша
А мне нужно чтобы выводило в следующем виде
Гриша
Маша
Паша

Где ошибка? Мне просто нужно из сессии записать значения в новые строки!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете цикл по $_SESSION['name'], в ней результат работы функции explode(';',$_SESSION['name']) или исходная строка? Кроме того, так как у вас три значения, то вам нужно и три переменные или три элемента массива под них.

```
$arr = explode(';',$_SESSION['name']);
$peremennaya = [];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
  echo $value."<br />";
  $peremennaya[] = $value;
}
echo $peremennaya[0]."<br />";
echo $peremennaya[1]."<br />";
echo $peremennaya[2]."<br />";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я думаю это то что нужно! И моя ошибка была в том что я не записывал каждое значение в новый массив, а именно я забыл что-то вроде этого $peremennaya[] = $value;

Comment: К сожалению тож что то не то, мне нужно из массива или из супер глобального массива взять каждое значение и поместить в таблицу вот мой код: if ( !empty($_SESSION['names'] { explode.... Foreach (session explode as $value) { $tr[] = <tr> Value</tr>} и внизу в html вывожу $tr но опЯть 25, последнее значение отображается в таблице, а нужно чтобы все значения добавились с новой строки

Answer (score 0):

Лучше создать пустую переменную в начале и потом дополнять её.

```
$peremennaya = ""
foreach ($_SESSION['name'] as $value) {
  $peremennaya .= '<tr>'.$value.'</tr>';
}
```

В Вашем же коде переменная постоянно менялась и логично, что выводила последнее подставленное значение. Оператор .= конкатенирует переменную и строку, которая идёт после оператора.